# Why is this solution that I found online to have collapsible product categories menu in WordPress not working?

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

**OBJECTIVE**

I would like my product categories sidebar menu to be collapsible like so:

[image]

This is one of the pages where the categories are displayed:

https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=feminino

**WHAT I TRIED**

I found [this solution](https://gist.github.com/Garconis/b750bee39aed5f0e8e596bb2fac16cab) online. I followed the instructions and added the CSS to the site's custom CSS section and used the Insert Headers and Footers plugin to insert the JQuery.

**JQuery:**

```
jQuery(function($){
    // add a new toggle element after the parent category anchor
    $( "<div class='woo-cat-toggle'></div>" ).insertAfter( "#sidebar .widget_product_categories .product-categories > .cat-item.cat-parent > a" );
    // when the new toggle element is clicked, add/remove the class that controls visibility of children
    $( "#sidebar .widget_product_categories .product-categories .woo-cat-toggle" ).click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("cat-popped");
    });
    // if the parent category is the current category or a parent of an active child, then show the children categories too
    $('#sidebar .widget_product_categories .product-categories > .cat-item.cat-parent').each(function(){
        if($(this).is('.current-cat, .current-cat-parent')) {
            $(this).children('.woo-cat-toggle').toggleClass("cat-popped");
        } 
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
/* - woo cat toggling elements, injected via jQuery - */

/* make list item be relative, to be able to position toggle within this item, if desired */
#sidebar .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent {
    position: relative; 
}
/* the new toggle element wrapper, which is added via jQuery */
#sidebar .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
/* when it's popped, style the toggle wrapper differently */
#sidebar .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle.cat-popped {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    background: rgba(0,24,113,1);
    color: white;
}
/* toggle icon */
#sidebar .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle::before {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: none;
    speak: none;
    content: '+';
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* toggle icon when triggered */
#sidebar .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle.cat-popped::before {
    content: '\2013';
}
/* hide sub cats by default */
#sidebar .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle ~ ul.children {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
/* show sub cats when triggered via jQuery toggle */
#sidebar .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle.cat-popped ~ ul.children {
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

Nothing seems to happen at all. Unfortunately I am not overly familiar with either JQuery or CSS so I am at a complete loss.

**WEBSITE URL**

https://saddhustore.com.br/

And a specific page:

https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=feminino

Comment: Hi. Could you update your question by posting your code and not just pictures of your code? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Hi! Sure thing, thanks so much for pointing it out